# How can I do a laravel filter that accepts two inputs or just one

Tags: php, laravel

So, i have a database with students, and i have, names, group name of students, and something like that, I want to make a filter system, with multiple filter, for example i want to display row (of table) with Students with name John and are in group A (both conditions must be). But the problem is when i want a filter only for students, for example i don't need a particular group, my script doesn't work, only for two filters, no only one.

I tried this:

in route: `Route::post('/search', 'HomeController@search')->name('search');`
in HomeController:

```
public function search(Request $request)
{
     $students = Student::query();
     $datas = $request->all();


    if ($request->has('group')) {
        $students = $students->where('group', $request->group);
    }

    if ($request->has('name')) {
        $students = $students->where('name', $request->name);
    }

    $students = $students->paginate(40);
    $data = array (
        'students' => $students,
        'datas' => $datas,
    );
    return view('searchStudent')->with($data);
}
```

And in blade, two simple inputs, button, and the table with students.

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
   <div class="search-box grey lighten-3">
      <h2>Search Students</h2>
      <div class="input-r">
         <form action="{{ route('search') }}" method="post">
            @csrf
            <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control">
            <input name="group" type="text" class="form-control">
            <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" type="submit">Search</button>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
   @foreach ($students as $student)
   <div class="row pb-5">
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="profiel-img">
            <img src="{{ asset($student->image) }}" alt="thumbnail" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 200px">
         </div>
         <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="font-size: 12px; margin-left: 40px;" href="{{ route('student.show', $student) }}">Visit Profile</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 pb-3">
         <h3 class="black-text"> {{ $student->name }}</h3>
         <h3 class="black-text"> {{ $student->group }}</h3>
         <hr style="border-top:1px solid #ccc;">
      </div>
   </div>
   @endforeach
   {{ $students->appends($datas)->links() }}
</div>
```

I need to work for only name input, and filter, only for group, and for both input. With this code, it works only for both (i can't filter only name, only group, etc. )

Comment: try to add $students->orWhere('name', $request->name);

Comment: it works for only one, but now for both, doesn't work ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `$request->has()` determines if a value is present on the request. So they're always true since your inputs are present in the form, and `$students` will be queried on empty strings. Try using `$request->filled()` instead.

```
if ($request->filled('group')) {
    $students = $students->where('group', $request->group);
}

if ($request->filled('name')) {
    $students = $students->where('name', $request->name);
}
```

This is for [Laravel 7.x](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests)

Answer (score 1):

try to add

```
    if ($request->has('group')) {
        $students = $students->orWhere('group', $request->group);
    }

    if ($request->has('name')) {
        $students = $students->orWhere('name', $request->name);
    }
```